# Storage variables in UIButton for additional functionality

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton

I want to hold in variables and add new functions in UIButton.
I have tried with extension but with set and get, I could not able to do it. I have tried to create custom UIButton class, but now, I can't able use my functions and variables on my new button class in xcode.

How can I do?
Thank you...

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {
    //I want to be able to initialize MyUIButton like below
    @IBOutlet weak var button11: MyUIButton!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        //initialize the databaseAccessor class
        let appDelegate = UIApplication.shared.delegate as! AppDelegate
        let context = appDelegate.persistentContainer.viewContext
        DatabaseAccessor.shared = DatabaseAccessor(delegate: appDelegate, viewContext: context)

        // the code that I want to work is below
        button11.getLocation()

    }

    override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
        super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
        // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
    }


}


import UIKit

@IBDesignable
class MyUIButton: UIButton {

    /*
    // Only override draw() if you perform custom drawing.
    // An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        // Drawing code
    }
    */
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    @IBInspectable var purposeName = ""
    private var purposeIcon = ""
    private var location = 0

    func setPurposeName(name: String){
        purposeName = name
    }

    func getPurposeName()-> String{
        return purposeName
    }

    func setPurposeIcon(name: String){
        purposeIcon = name
    }

    func getPurposeIcon()-> String{
        return purposeIcon
    }

    func setLocation(location: Int){
        self.location = location
    }

    func getLocation()-> Int{
        return location
    }
}
```

I have done these but non of them has worked... I want to use functions that I made in viewController. Like

Comment: Show your code, please.

Comment: You need to show how you use this custom button class and its properties.

Comment: And so what is it that "doesn't work"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must not write separate setters and getters for your stored properties as functions.

```
var purposeName = ""
func setPurposeName(name: String){
    purposeName = name
}
func getPurposeName()-> String{
    return purposeName
}
```

Instead, you must make this a computed property, and implement its setter and getter, like this:

```
var _purposeName = ""
var purposeName {
    set { _purposeName = newValue }
    get { return _purposeName }
}
```

Apart from that there's nothing wrong with your code.